# One has something or lacks it (хватит/достаточно)

Tags: словоупотребление

I am more or less familiar with the conecept behind `хватает/хватило/хватит` and `достаточно` which is to say that one has something or lacks it.

Less formal: `(не) хватает/хватило/хватит`

More formal: `(не) достаточно`

I did an exercise regarding those two words and I had to guess which one to put into which gap. Let's take this short conversation as an example. For you as native speakers what exactly lets you choose the one or the other here? Personally I would choose the more formal one because the situation takes place in a workplace environment.

> **Начальник:** Тебе не хватает   опыта, внимания к деталям, терпения.
>
> **Подчинённый:** У меня достаточно   всего, о чём вы сказали. Я трудоспособный, терпеливый, быстро учусь.

Source: http://learnrussian.rt.com/lessons/styles-of-speech-constructions-of-sufficiency/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How to distinguish between the styles. The boss in your dialogue is not polite, he uses ты addressing his employee, and uses 'хватать, хватить' respectively. Though normally it shouldn't be like this. The employee cannot behave the same way. He uses вы and достаточно.It is formal and polite.But then comes the difference in the meaning and mixture of styles.

Besides, you can see the structure is different. Кому? Мне, тебе не хватает.Чего, у кого достаточно.

Начальник: Ты хотел со мной поговорить, Степан?
Подчинённый: Да, Михаил Петрович. Я хочу стать начальником департамента продаж. Я знаю, что вы ищете нового начальника. Я много работаю, у меня хорошие продажи. Все клиенты мной довольны.
Начальник: Этого ...Недостаточно....(not enough).... , чтобы стать начальником департамента.
Подчинённый: А чего мне не ....хватает.....(lack).. ?
Начальник: Тебе не ....хватает....(lack)... опыта, внимания к деталям, терпения.
Подчинённый: У меня ......достаточно...(enough).. всего, о чём вы сказали. Я трудоспособный, терпеливый, быстро учусь.
Начальник: Не думаю, что это так.
Подчинённый: А у Андрея есть все эти качества, чтобы стать начальником департамента? Я знаю, что он тоже хочет получить это место. А ведь он работает только три месяца в нашей компании!
Начальник: ...хватит...(stop it)..... говорить об этом. Я сам буду решать, кто станет начальником отдела продаж. Всё, на сегодня ....(достаточно )(enough)..... , иди работать.

More about these words.

. **Достаточно** appeared in the Russian language at the end of the18th century as a bookish word and was used in the scientific language. Later it was widespread in the official style.  Хватит is informal.

1.If you know something *достаточно хорошо*, you know it rather well.

> Когда-то он изучал физику достаточно глубоко.

2. *Достаточно* means "as much as it is necessary* for something  Хватать has the same meaning (informal)

   > Он получает достаточно. | Вы достаточно потрудились в этом полугодии. | Месяца вполне достаточно, чтобы подготовиться.
   >   На жизнь ему хватает денег. Чтобы подготовиться, месяца хватит вполне.
   >   — Вы не мало ли взяли с собой еды в дорогу? — Достаточно.
   >   Не маловато ли ты взял с собой еды?--Мне хватит.

**Недостаточно, не хватает** means *insufficient*.

> Нe хватает /недостаточно времени для близких, для детей. | Не хватает ласки, нежности, тепла, общения. |
>   Не хватило денег, чтобы купить что-либо.
>   Компьютеру не хватает памяти.

3 as a predicative If there is something **больше чем достаточно,** it means the quantity or number is too much, or too many.

> Умеющих играть на гитаре оказалось больше чем достаточно. | Идей у него больше чем достаточно.

4 as a predicative **достаточно сделать** something to achieve a result means 'you will get a result as soon as you do something.

> Мне достаточно посмотреть на страницу в течение двадцати секунд, и я её запомню. | Достаточно пропустить один день занятий, чтобы тебя исключили.

5. as a predicative When you say **чего-либо достаточно** you mean "it is enough" "you don't need more", "stop it". It is more polite. Хватит is also used, but sounds a bit rude.

> Достаточно музыки! | Перестань, достаточно!
>   Хватит! Перестань!

Хватать, хватить.more meanings.

1.If you say,**вас на всё (всех) не хватает**, it means you cannot multitask or take care of several people .

2.If you say, **вам чего-либо не хватает для полного счастья**, it means you have a lot, but you still need something to be fully satisfied.

3.If you say **кого-то не хватает**, you miss them

> Страшно не хватает мудрого друга. | Ты ведь знаешь, что мне не хватает тебя.

4. Idioms **его (нам) только не хватало**--you don't want their presence in your company
   **Этого нам (мне) только не хватало**--said when there is something unexpected which can serve an obstacle.

Answer (score 2):

to my taste the style of `мне хватает всего` is lower and in the given situation a response reusing `хватает` picked up from the boss' statement but in opposite meaning would sound confrontational

as far as the connotation is concerned in this situation `достаточно` sounds more objective, `хватает` when applied to oneself has this spirit of *being enough for me* which may not be so for someone else or meet certain criteria

`достаточно` also has a connotation of *sufficiency for the time being* which may change later on, whereas `хватать` has an *undertone of constancy*